# Internet connection issues after removing virus

Tags: windows-7, virus

I have been infected by a virus that changed my browser's proxy. This was apparently (part of) internet.exe. I have removed this, and any associated files I could find. But I'm still having connection issues. I fixed it in my browsers (resetting proxies), but any other programs that connect to the internet are having connection problems, including windows update.

Does anybody know how I can reset all proxies? Or are there any registry keys or other programs associated with Internet.exe?

I'm on W7 by the way.

Comment: I found the problem..

Seems like I forgot to change the proxy on IE as well.

Comment: Its an important note that the Internet Explorer connection options are actually the *Windows* connection options. So what appear to be the IE options are the global default for your operating system.

Comment: @jcrawfordor: Thanks! Didn't know that.

@slhck: I'm gonna add it as an answer as soon as I can ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it was a virus the most simple way to fix this is by doing a simple "System Restore" this will take the computer back to a day you know the computer was working.

This can be done by:

- Start
- Search (Little box below "All Programes")
- System Restore

Long Way if XP or less -

- Start
- All Programes
- Accessories
- System Tools
- System Restore

Follow the on screen instructions, then pick a date you know the computer was working. This will clean the registery issues and fix most system issues. Remember to run a virus scan after. Simple AVG's Free Version would be ok just to give it a test.